# jersey multiparty returns NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/ExtractorException

Tags: java, rest, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

i am trying to create an api that consumes/uploads an image file

i have configured my app like this:

ResourceConfig file

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
 public class appConfig extends ResourceConfig {
public appConfig() {
    // Register resources and providers using package-scanning.
    packages("src.main.java.org.vaad.vaadAPI");
    register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    register(LoggingFilter.class);

    // temp disabled for testing 

}
```

Resource File :

```
@POST
@Path("/user/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
         @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) {
    String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = "C://Upload_Files/";
    String filePath = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER + contentDispositionHeader.getFileName();

    // save the file to the server
//  saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);

    String output = "File saved to server location : " + filePath;

    return Response.status(200).build();

}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>0.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
    <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.21</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.21</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.21</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Jersey Multipart entity providers support module -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>
```

but when loading the server i get the following err :

```
Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [133] milliseconds.
Aug 30, 2015 2:25:18 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 30, 2015 2:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/ExtractorException
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.createValueFactory(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:439)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractValueFactoryProvider.getValueFactory(AbstractValueFactoryProvider.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getValueFactory(ParameterValueHelper.java:145)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.createValueProviders(ParameterValueHelper.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Invocable.getValueProviders(Invocable.java:322)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.checkValueProviders(ResourceMethodValidator.java:164)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.checkMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.visitJaxrsResourceMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.visitResourceMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethod.accept(ResourceMethod.java:854)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.access$000(ComponentModelValidator.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator$1.run(ComponentModelValidator.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validate(ComponentModelValidator.java:146)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:320)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1034)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ExtractorException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    ... 47 more

Aug 30, 2015 2:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [appConfig] in web application [/vaad2] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ExtractorException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.createValueFactory(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:439)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractValueFactoryProvider.getValueFactory(AbstractValueFactoryProvider.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getValueFactory(ParameterValueHelper.java:145)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.createValueProviders(ParameterValueHelper.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Invocable.getValueProviders(Invocable.java:322)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.checkValueProviders(ResourceMethodValidator.java:164)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.checkMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.visitJaxrsResourceMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.visitResourceMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethod.accept(ResourceMethod.java:854)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.access$000(ComponentModelValidator.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator$1.run(ComponentModelValidator.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validate(ComponentModelValidator.java:146)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:320)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1034)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Aug 30, 2015 2:25:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 30, 2015 2:25:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 30, 2015 2:25:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6006 ms
Aug 30, 2015 3:32:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/vaad2] has started
Aug 30, 2015 3:32:51 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 30, 2015 3:32:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/ExtractorException
    at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.createValueFactory(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:439)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractValueFactoryProvider.getValueFactory(AbstractValueFactoryProvider.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getValueFactory(ParameterValueHelper.java:145)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.createValueProviders(ParameterValueHelper.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Invocable.getValueProviders(Invocable.java:322)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.checkValueProviders(ResourceMethodValidator.java:164)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.checkMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.visitJaxrsResourceMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.visitResourceMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethod.accept(ResourceMethod.java:854)
    at
```

i couldn't find any thing referring this exception    plz help

Comment: What server are you deploying to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution. The jersey common was not updated. so you need to update the dependency version from 2.13 -> 2.21.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
    <version>2.21</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Helped me out. Thanks

Comment: This was very helpful to me, good job!

Answer (score 2):

This is my pom file - and It worked for me,I specifically added

```
    <!--  using jersey-multipart for multipart file upload dependency on @FormInputParam that is required -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.21</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is the rest of the pom.xml file -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>RestFileUpload</groupId>
  <artifactId>RestFileUpload</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>


        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <!-- changes the default location of war deployment -->
                        <!-- commented it since we are directly deploying war to the ${catalina_home}/webapps -->
                        <!-- <warName>${warfilename}</warName> -->
                        <!-- <outputDirectory>${catalina_home}/webapps</outputDirectory> -->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <!-- we need the maven-compiler to compile java files in jdk version 
                    1.8 hence setting the source and the target -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>



                <!-- added to deploy maven build to remote tomcat, update = true :: redeploy's 
                    the war files on update use the command : mvn clean tomcat7:deploy , which 
                    will deploy to TOMCAT 7 , ALREADY RUNNING. YOU NEED TO START THE TOMCAT SERVER 
                    FIRST. To start tomcat 7: mvn tomcat7:start -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>${remotedeployserverurl}</url>
                        <server>tomcat7</server>
                        <path>/${project.groupId}</path>
                        <!-- configuring the tomcat7 to update itself while deploying -->
                        <update>true</update>
                        <!-- added this on 25 April -->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <!-- Associate the read-project-properties goal with the initialize 
                            phase, to read the properties file. -->
                        <execution>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <files>
                                    <!-- taking the build.properties from the relative location of the 
                                        pom file -->
                                    <file>${propertiesfilelocation}</file>
                                </files>
                                <!-- tomcat7 listed in server node can be found in /maven/conf/setting.xml 
                                    mapping username and password are defined in tomcat7_directory/conf/tomcat-users.xml -->
                                <server>tomcat7</server>
                                <username>${tomcat.manager.username}</username>
                                <password>${tomcat.manager.password}</password>
                                <url>${tomcat.manager.url}</url>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>



            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <!-- customize the catalina_home for remote deployment for tomcat7, the 
        remotedeployserverurl is http://localhost:8080/manager/text and for tomcat6 
        http://localhost:8080/manager/html -->
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <warfilename>${project.groupId}</warfilename>
        <!-- change the url to : http://45.79.143.163:8080/manager/text -->
        <remotedeployserverurl> http://45.79.143.163:8080/manager/text</remotedeployserverurl>
        <propertiesfilelocation>src/main/resources/build.properties</propertiesfilelocation>
        <jersey2.version>2.19</jersey2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- to convert the json and parse json object -->


        <!-- spring dependency starts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- spring framework just added ends here -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- jersey dependencies ends -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jersey dependency ends -->

        <!-- apache dbcp commons was added here , because we need threadpooling 
            mechanism for database (Database connection pooling) -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId> <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId> 
            <version>1.4</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- used for httpclient library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mysql dependency here -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- adding for log4j dependency for logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Added 25 May: added the dependency for Jax-RS 2.0 jersey core Servlet 
            3.x implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added 25 May: for jersey-client implementation -->
         <dependency> 
             <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId> 
             <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId> 
             <version>2.21</version> 
        </dependency> 

        <!-- dependency resolved for jax-rs -->


        <!-- Uses this dependency to read from build.properties file. The artifact 
            id # properties-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--configured the datasource to tomcat-jdbc in spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- added because StringUTils was present in package, and for null checks -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

    <!--  using jersey-multipart for multipart file upload dependency on @FormInputParam that is required -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.21</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This would be my web.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>RestFileUpload</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>fileupload.html</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
  <!--  this will specify the root package for the RESTservice being consumed
         we define the servlet class to be ServletContainer because we are using Jax-RS 2.0
   -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>fileuploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>pkgs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
</init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fileuploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>




</web-app>
```