# NodeList.getLength() returning 0 in Java 11

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xerces, java-11

I am migrating my application from Java 8 to Java 11. In Java 8, my input xml file was parsing correctly, but in Java 11 the `nodeList.getLength()` is returning `0`.
Please refer the code as per which I am always getting the error: `Cannot find signature`.

I have tried using `document.getElementsByTagName("Signature")` instead of `getElementsByTagNameNS()`, which returns correct `length`. However the `unmarshalXMLSignature()` method then gives an error that Document implementation must support DOM Level 2 and be namespace aware.
Is there any challenge with using `getElementsByTagNameNS()` method in Java 11?

```
private DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
. . .
document = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(input);
final NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");
if (nodeList.getLength() == 0) {
    throw new SecurityException("Cannot find signature");
}
final XMLValidateContext validateContext = new DOMValidateContext(newX509KeySelector(), nodeList.item(0));
final XMLSignature signature = getXMLSignatureFactory().unmarshalXMLSignature(validateContext);
. . .
```

Edit 1: The input xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><License>
        <id>999</id>
        <companyName>TRXX</companyName>
        <creationDate>01-01-2016</creationDate>
        <expirationDate>never</expirationDate>
        <features>
            <feature>
                <name>drwwy</name>
                <value>true</value>
                <description>drwwy module</description>
            </feature>
            <feature>
                <name>pnp</name>
                <value>true</value>
                <description>Index Number Management module</description>
            </feature>
        </features>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><Reference URI="">
<Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>l5Cl4E=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>R3zBkE=</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo><X509Data><X509SubjectName>CN=TRXX Inc,OU=Product Development,O=TRXX Inc,L=Scotle,ST=Atlanta,C=US</X509SubjectName><X509Certificate>MIY</X509Certificate>
</X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature></License>
```

Edit 2: I figured out, earlier I was injecting DocumentBuilderFactory which is part of JDK , but it is no longer allowed in Java 11. That is why I instantiated it  using DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(), but with this one my nodelist length comes as zero. Can we use any other way to instantiate DocumentBuilderFactory  object ?

Comment: Please add the XML to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks @KarolDowbecki, added the input XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `document.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");` you get an empty nodeList and the source code provided throws your `new SecurityException("Cannot find signature")`.

If you `document.getElementsByTagName("Signature")`, the Signature element is found but without namespace awareness, throwing this exception later on:

```
javax.xml.crypto.MarshalException: Document implementation must support DOM Level 2 and be namespace aware
  at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory.unmarshal(DOMXMLSignatureFactory.java:189)
  at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory.unmarshalXMLSignature(DOMXMLSignatureFactory.java:150)
```

When researching the term `getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature")` I found code examples where they activate namespace awareness on the new instance of DocumentBuilderFactory manually:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

This should fix your `new SecurityException("Cannot find signature")` issue.

Regarding [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53814919/openwebbeans-cdi-failing-in-java-11) you not only migrated Java 8 to 11, but also CDI API, OpenWebBeans, Apache Tomcat and maybe other modules too, someone else must have done this activation of namespace awareness for you previously.
Or saying it differently - you @Injected a namespace aware DocumentBuilderFactory instance.

**Edit:**

For manual configuration and injection of `DocumentBuilderFactory`, create a method that `@Produces` an instance of the `DocumentBuilderFactory` and provides that instance for injection elsewhere:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

@Dependent
public class DocumentBuilderFactoryProducer {
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public DocumentBuilderFactory createDocumentBuilderFactory() {
        DocumentBuilderFactory result = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        result.setNamespaceAware(true);
        // other customizations ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

This can be injected into other beans like so:

```
@Inject
private DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was using in Java 8, but without the @ApplicationScoped. Added  the annotation at class level and it solved my issue.

Comment: This detail plus source code could have speed up reproducing and answering your previous question by days. Didn't even know about the `@Produces` annotation. But due to this I learned a lot about CDI :-)